# I see boxes instead of font in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, fonts

I am using termite as my terminal. I have added font option in my config:

```
[options]
font = xos4 Terminus 12px
```

But after restarting my terminal I see only boxes instead of font.

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

**upd**: font from package `terminus-font-otb` works correctly but I want to know why usual terminus font doesn't work.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pango/issues/386), pango library, which is responsible for text rendering in many programs from GNOME but also XFCE project stopped supporting bitmap (PCF, BDF) fonts. Only fix is to downgrade to a pango version of 1.43 (which I don't recommend because of how many packages rely on it) or to move to a desktop environment that doesn't depend on this library.